# UIImageView on iphone 4 image is half way out of view

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uiimage

I am creating an app with a simple `UIImageview` and scroll view for zooming.
Everything is perfect on my iPhone5/s. However, when I test the app on the iPhone 4S it does not work correctly. When I use a modal to pop the image full screen, the image is half way off the screen. 
Again, this ONLY happens on the 4S and not the 5.

[image: iphone 4s image half way off screen]

I tried changing the anchor points, forcing sizing but nothing works

Also, after I change my orientation from portrait to land scape and back, it goes back into "position"

I am also using constraints as my scrollview is horizontal and vertical center in my main view and the image view is horizontal vertical center in the scroll view.

Thank you in advance.

some relevant code:

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.myImage];
[self.scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
[self.myView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

[im setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
im.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale
                     animated:YES];

NSLog(@"%F",img.size.height);
CGFloat imgheight = image.size.height;
CGFloat imgwidth = image.size. width;
CGSize imageSize = [self currentScreenBoundsDependOnOrientation];

self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                   0,
                                   imageSize.width,
                                   imageSize.height);

self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                  0,
                                  imageSize.width,
                                  imageSize.height);
dan = true;    
self.scrollView.delegate = self;

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.4;
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
self.scrollView.zoomScale = self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale;
```

Comment: I would appreciate some insight rather than edits Moxy

Comment: My edit was to make your code and question more readable! 
P.S. Use '@' before a username so that user would be notified of your comment.